# How to properly get table-row indexes and named values from trapped var-binds in pysnmp

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysnmp

I'm trying to keep my code as clean as possible but I'm not completely satisfied with what I achieved so far.

I built a SNMP manager which receive traps from another device using a custom MIB, which I will refer to as MY-MIB.

I am not sure this is the cleanest way, but essentially I have:

```
from pysnmp.entity import engine, config
from pysnmp.carrier.asynsock.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import ntfrcv, context
from pysnmp.smi import builder, rfc1902
from pysnmp.smi.view import MibViewController
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import mibvar

_snmp_engine = engine.SnmpEngine()
_snmpContext = context.SnmpContext(_snmpEngine)
_mibBuilder = _snmpContext.getMibInstrum().getMibBuilder()
#Add local path where MY-MIB is located
_mibSources = _mibBuilder.getMibSources() + (builder.DirMibSource('.'),)
_mibBuilder.setMibSources(*mibSources)
_mibBuilder.loadModules('MY-MIB')
_view_controller = MibViewController(_mibBuilder)    


def my_callback_trap_processor(snmp_engine, state_reference,
                                   context_id, context_name, var_binds, ctx):

    #...CALLBACK CODE...


config.addV1System(snmp_engine, 'my-area', 'MYCOMMUNITY')
config.addTargetParams(snmp_engine, 'my-creds', 'my-area',
                       'noAuthNoPriv', 1)

config.addSocketTransport(snmp_engine,
                          udp.domainName + (1,),
                          udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode((IP_ADDRESS,
                                                             PORT)))

ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(snmp_engine, my_callback_trap_processor)

snmp_engine.transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)

try:
    snmp_engine.transportDispatcher.runDispatcher()
except:
    snmp_engine.transportDispatcher.closeDispatcher()
    raise
```

In the callback function above I can get a pretty intelligible print by just using the following code:

```
    varBinds = [rfc1902.ObjectType(rfc1902.ObjectIdentity(x[0]), x[1]).resolveWithMib(_view_controller) for x in var_binds]
    for varBind in varBinds:
        print(varBind.prettyPrint())
```

which, from a given trap that I receive, gives me:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0 = 0
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0 = MY-MIB::myNotificationType
MY-MIB::myReplyKey.47746."ABC" = 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000
MY-MIB::myTime.0 = 20171115131544Z
MY-MIB::myOperationMode.0 = 'standalone'
```

Nice. But I want to manipulate/dissect each bit of information from the given var-binds, especially in a higher level way.

Looking at the innards of the library I was able to gather this code up:

```
for varBind in var_binds:   
    objct = rfc1902.ObjectIdentity(varBind[0]).resolveWithMib(self._view_controller)
    (symName, modName), indices = mibvar.oidToMibName(
                self._view_controller, objct.getOid()
                )
    print(symName, modName, indices, varBind[1])
```

that gives me:

```
sysUpTime SNMPv2-MIB (Integer(0),) 0
snmpTrapOID SNMPv2-MIB (Integer(0),) 1.3.6.1.X.Y.Z.A.B.C.D
myReplyKey MY-MIB (myTimeStamp(47746), myName(b'X00080')) 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000
myTime MY-MIB (Integer(0),) 20171115131544Z
myOperationMode MY-MIB (Integer(0),) 1
```

and in the case of myReplyKey indexes I can just do a:

```
    for idx in indices:
        try:
            print(idx.getValue())
        except AttributeError:
            print(int(idx))
```

But in the case of the `myOperationMode` var-bind, how do I get the named-value `'standalone'` instead of `1`? And how to get the names of the indexes (`myTimeStamp` and `myName`)?

**Update:**

After Ilya's suggestions I researched the library a little bit more for getting the namedValues and, also, I used some Python hacking to get what I was looking for on the indices.

```
varBinds = [rfc1902.ObjectType(rfc1902.ObjectIdentity(x[0]), x[1]).resolveWithMib(_view_controller) for x in var_binds]
processed_var_binds = []
for var_bind in resolved_var_binds:   

    object_identity, object_value = var_bind
    mod_name, var_name, indices = object_identity.getMibSymbol()

    var_bind_dict = {'mib': mod_name, 'name': var_name, 'indices': {}}

    for idx in indices:
        try:
            value = idx.getValue()
        except AttributeError:
            var_bind_dict['indices'] = int(idx.prettyPrint())
        else:
            var_bind_dict['indices'][type(value).__name__] = str(value)

    try:
        var_bind_dict['value'] = object_value.namedValues[object_value]
    except (AttributeError, KeyError):
        try:
            var_bind_dict['value'] = int(object_value.prettyPrint())
        except ValueError:
            var_bind_dict['value'] = object_value.prettyPrint()

    processed_var_binds.append(var_bind_dict)
```

Comment: Try `varBind[1].prettyPrint()` to get the named value. Although I am not sure what is your ultimate goal wrt the dissection. Do you want to get hold of MIB name, MIB object and possible indices?

Comment: I had already tried it, but in fact it complains that one positional argument is missing. So I even tried `varBind[1].prettyPrint(varBind[1])` which still gives me `1`

Comment: And how to get the names of the indexes (`myTimeStamp` and `myName`) when looping through them?

Comment: @Ilya "Do you want to get hold of MIB name, MIB object and possible indices?" Yes, and values, named-values when existent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve SNMP PDU var-bindings against a MIB you can use [this snippet](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/smi/manager/browsing-mib-tree.html#pdu-var-binds-to-mib-objects) what I think you have done already:

```
from pysnmp.smi.rfc1902 import *

var_binds = [ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(x[0]), x[1]).resolveWithMib(mibViewController)
            for x in var_binds]
```

By this point you have a list of [rfc1902.ObjectType](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectType) objects. The `ObjectType` instance mimics a two-element tuple: [ObjectIdentity](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectIdentity) and [SNMP value object](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#snmp-base-types).

```
var_bind = var_binds[0]
object_identity, object_value = var_bind
```

Now, [getMibSymbol()](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#pysnmp.smi.rfc1902.ObjectIdentity.getMibSymbol) will give you MIB name, MIB object name and the tuple of indices made up from the trailing part of the OID. Index elements are [SNMP value objects](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/api-reference.html#snmp-base-types) just as `object_value`:

```
>>> object_identity.getMibSymbol()
('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', (0,))
```

The enumeration, should it present, is reported by `.prettyPrint()`:

```
>>> from pysnmp.proto.rfc1902 import *
>>> Error = Integer.withNamedValues(**{'disk-full': 1, 'no-disk': -1})
>>> error = Error(1)
>>> error.prettyPrint()
'disk-full'
>>> int(error)
1
```